# How to upgrade Firebase Firestore API from v1 to v2 inside the Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've read the docs for upgrading the Cloud functions to version 2 [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade). But I also need to upgrade the FireStore API (Inside the cloud functions), and no docs there (that I could find).

```
import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'; // new version 2 - OK
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin'; // Old version - need to upgrade
```

Stack : `NodeJs 18 cloud functions, "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0","firebase-functions": ^4.3.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the docs were [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen), inside the FireStore section.

This is the new FireStore API:

```
import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import { firestore, initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin'; // Old version - need to upgrade
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'; // new version v2
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'; // new version v2
```